# What are Devout units?

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

On my current play through my Hero can be upgraded with a skill "Dirty Half Dozen", this causes all the units in the Hero's party to obtain +3 damage versus Devout units.

Now, I'm wondering, what are Devout units? Is this a race I have yet to discover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Devout: The unit deals +3 (physical) damage  against Heretic units and
>   is affected by certain types of abilities, spells and effects (e.g.
>   Unholy Champion, Holy War).

The Devout/Heretic concepts are modifiers used by Theocrat leaders.  Evangelist, Exalted and Martyr units are automatically Devout.

The *Mark of the Heretic* spell causes an army to be marked as Heretics.

Comment: So can units of types other than the 3 listed become devout?

Comment: Sure - "Order of the Templar Knights" is a theocrat empire upgrade which causes Infantry and Cavalry units to be devout.  "Order of Sacred Support" causes Support units to be devout.